# Problems with a differential equation: $y'=|y|+x^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'=|y|+x^2$$
Write the solution to the Cauchy problem with $y(a)=0$ for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and tell for what values of $a$ the solution is of class $C^2(\mathbb{R})$.

What I tried: The solutions don't look always positive or always negative, so I thought of a function defined joining the solutions to the two linear differential equations, but I couldn't figure out how to do that. Since the derivative must always be $\ge0$ then the solution must be monotone, but how do I join the two solutions? Is that even the way to go?

The solutions to the linear equations are $$f_1(x)=Ae^x-x^2-2x-2\\f_2(x)=Be^{-x}+x^2-2x+2$$
which give me the two constants $A$ and $B$ $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$A=e^{-a}(a^2+2a+2)\\B=e^a(-a^2+2a-2)$$
$A$ is always positive, $B$ is always negative. In particular, by construction the solution must have a zero in $a$, and for $x>a$ it must be $\ge0$ because of the differential equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $y(a) = 0$ you can solve separately for $x > a$ (which will give $y>0$) and $x < a$ (which gives $y < 0$). This is what you did, I think it's done correctly. It's your $f_1(x)$ for $x > a$ and $f_2(x)$ for $x < a$.